# Problems with modRewrite 

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site on my local machine, it's address is `ikot` and I have a .htaccess file which contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off


php_value memory_limit 64M

RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$   /index.php?level[0]=$1&depth=1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$   /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&depth=2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$                   /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&level[2]=$3&depth=3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$      /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&level[2]=$3&level[3]=$4&depth=4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$       /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&level[2]=$3&level[3]=$4&level[4]=$5&depth=5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$       /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&level[2]=$3&level[3]=$4&level[4]=$5&level[5]=$6&depth=6 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)[/]?$       /index.php?level[0]=$1&level[1]=$2&level[2]=$3&level[3]=$4&level[4]=$5&level[5]=$6&level[6]=$7&depth=7 [L,QSA]
```

And when I type in my browser address `ikot/media`, it redirects me (with 301 code) to 
`http://ikot/media/?level[0]=media&depth=1`

There is no problems with other addresses, for example `ikot/cats` works correct.

I think it's rewire rule problem cause I've used send debug breakpoints and they don't work. That means code execution have not start.

*i found more specific reason of this problem. if at server there is folder with smae name as address, error'll occur. For example, if i write ikot.ru/media and i have folder at server with this name (media) (in project main folder), there'll be trash in address, else adress'll be correct*

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a [really awesome tool](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/) that will let you try out your rewrite rules without the need to constantly edit your .htaccess file and refresh your browser. Though **I have to question why** you're using the rewrites to manually create the directory structure like that. You might consider the front controller pattern to simply write all those levels to the query string of a single script -- then you'll only have one rewrite rule and let PHP decide where to route the request and send the appropriate headers.

Comment: First of all, try it in other browsers. I have similar "odd" things in firefox when it caches old wrong redirect rule and appends it on top of the fresh debugged one.

Comment: i found more specific reason of this problem. if at server there is folder with smae name as address, error'll occur. For example, if i write ikot.ru/media and i have folder at server with this name (media) (in project main folder), there'll be trash in address, else adress'll be correct.

Comment: solved by adding DirectorySlash Off to .htaccess